# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'. How to fix it from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I don't know about virtual environments and what they do, but all I wanted was to start learning this tutorial on python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-n40rB1XaJ0ak1bemvlqumQ

I did everything possible:

```
pip install selenium

pip3 install selenium
```

installed and uninstalled it

Added it in my environmental variables in the path. Like this:

[image]

Now what am I supposed to do? In Visual Studio Code I'm still getting this error no matter what I do and how many times I install, uninstall and add it to my environmental variables:

[image]

Comment: It is likely that you have 2 Python installations and `pip` is installing in one but VScode is looking at the other. To find out where `pip`  is installing do `pip --version`. Compare what that says with what VScode says your Python interpreter is.

Comment: Yes I had 2. Thanks a lot! So I solved this by adding the version of the python I wanted it to be downloaded in with "pip3.10"

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the path to the file at the beginning of the file.
for example

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\workspace\pythontest\.venv\lib\site-packages')
```

Hope it helps you.